# QueryLimited(toLast:1) firebase Chat Mesenger Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a chat messenger app, and i would like to show the last sent message on home menu as shown:

[image]

and my database looks like

[image]

in my view did load, i am putting a function of getAllMsg()

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Private Message"
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    getAllMsg()
}
```

But in my `getAllMsg()` function, I am unsure how should I access the last message for each recipient. I used this code:

```
func getAllMsg() {
    self.users = []

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("privateMessages")
    ref.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
    }
        }
```

and I am getting the whole messages sent to my last recipient. Does anyone have any idea how should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `Database.database().reference("privateMessages").queryLimited(toLast: 1)`, which means that the database goes to `/privateMessages` and then gets the last child under that. That child is an entire user's worth of messages, not just the last message.

If you want the last message for a specific user you should start your query at that user's node:

```
// this code assumes there is a current user
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
let ref = Database.database().reference("privateMessages").child(user.uid)
```

Now you want to query this user's messages, assumedly either by timestamp or by the key (which is also chronological). For the latter you'd do:

```
ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toLast: 1).observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot)
}
```

Comment: but there isn't any user.uid nodes, the nodes were named after senderID_receiverID...

Comment: Ah... then you'll need to know the UIDs of both users. Firebase Database filters and returns the child nodes directly under the location where you execute the query. It cannot skip a level. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested

Comment: OK, am able to know my own UID, just the other party I couldnt find a way to get it from swift. will be thinking about it..